# get custom table frequency in R

Tags: r, frequency

Suppose I have the following vector.

```
test <- c(0.3,1.0,0.8,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.7,0.0,0.7,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.3,0.6,0.3,0.1)
```

Is there a way to get non logical frequency table such as?

Frequency between 0 and 0.1

Frequency between 0.2 and 0.4

Frequency between 0.5 and 0.8

Frequency between 0.9 and 1

Thanks

Comment: "Between" means inclusive on both sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few extra unnecessary groups in here but you can ignore those or subset them

```
table(cut(test, breaks = c(0,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.9,1)))
```

Comment: same idea I was using but I don't think you've set the arguments correct to give what the OP is after, though as Matthew points out this is slightly confusing language being used.

Comment: The OP wants to ignore some values, namely 0.1-0.2, 0.4-0.5 and 0.8-0.9

Comment: @Jeremy Mathematically, yes.  In practice, no.  All the values are to the precision of 1/10, so perhaps there are no omitted intervals.

Comment: yeah with this dataset there are no omitted intervals so it makes the question not specific

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a dedicated function, but you could write your own:

```
test <- c(0.3,1.0,0.8,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.7,0.0,0.7,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.3,0.6,0.3,0.1)
mapply(function (start, end) { sum(test >= start & test <= end) },
       c(0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.9), # starts
       c(0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 1)) # ends
# [1]  3 11 10 4
```

The use of `mapply` is purely to vectorise over the starts and ends which you supply. Note `test` is hard-coded into this function and the endpoints are inclusive, so adjust as necessary, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
labs <- c("0 and 0.1", "0.2 and 0.4", "0.5 and 0.8", "0.9 and 1")
table(cut(test, c(0,  .2, .5, .9, 1.1), right = FALSE, labels = labs))

##   0 and 0.1 0.2 and 0.4 0.5 and 0.8   0.9 and 1 
##           3          11          10           4
```

Comment: that actually gives cuts at (0,0.2] (0.2,0.5] (0.5,0.9] (0.9,1.1] but the OP wants a specific subset of cuts

Comment: Yes that's what the OP wants though they've not used the correct language.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you really want to bin these as tenths, and there are no missing intervals, `findInterval` is made for the task.

Here, 1.0 is in a group by itself:

```
table(findInterval(test, c(0,.2, .5, .9, 1)))

##  1  2  3  4  5 
##  3 11 10  3  1
```

With this statement, 1.0 is in the last interval, with .9:

```
table(findInterval(test, c(0,.2, .5, .9, 1), rightmost.closed=T))

##  1  2  3  4 
##  3 11 10  4
```